# pygame window closing instantly? also python.QUIT weird?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Python window instantly closing?  Also python.QUIT not working?

I read a tutorial on how to draw a window in pygame and I literally copy and pasted the code, but it still fails to stay open.  Also `pygame.QUIT`, it says "Mode 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' member"
(I'm using Visual Studio Code)
So I tried event, `event.QUIT` which seemed to be fine according to debugger, but I don't know if that's even the same thing?

```
import pygame
background_colour = (255, 255, 255)
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tutorial 1')
screen.fill(background_colour)
running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == event.QUIT:
      pygame.display.flip()
```

I figured that it would stay open because of the while loop but it just instantly closes.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind it works fine.  it's actually because i misinterpreted the debugger, i just tried the code as is and ignored the debugger.  it worked.

```
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
```

I also fixed how to quit